# want to use VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS structure

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, storage

I want to do some task related to disc drive for that Microsoft provide me following link [VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  . from this document I want to use following function,

```
  typedef struct _VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS {
  ULONG       NumberOfDiskExtents;
  DISK_EXTENT Extents[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
} VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, *PVOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS;
```

MSDN says include **Ntddvol.h (include Ntddvol.h)** as header file to use above function. But there is no header file I found named with **Ntddvol.h (include Ntddvol.h)**  in Microsoft include directories.
So please tell me which package or any thing else should I install to get support of **VALUME_DISK_EXTENTS**.

Comment: Googling `Ntddvol.h` gives several links to the header.  If these links are unsuitable for you, it'd be good to explain why in your question.

Comment: @simonc no we cant more information i already try google for same..

Comment: Searching for the header will give you many links to it.  Why can't you copy the code from one of these links?

Comment: @simonc copying code of .h file dont solve problem . what about library associate with.

Comment: Your question only asks about a header file.  Did you look at any of the links that associate the header with device driver development kit (DDK)?  Have you tried installing that?  I'd also recommend updating your question - it currently does a very poor job of describing your actual problem.

Comment: The file you need is included in the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) but I agree with simonc - your question, for being a very specific one, is very vague. What are you trying to do and who is "they"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you read your mentioned document carefully you may found that its not part of usual studio so you must install some driver kit to use **VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS** .

If google with just "include Ntddvol.h" you may found information that to use this header file you need to install

[Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx)